# mmap on multiple nodes

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, mmap

The script below writes in parallel to a memory mapped array with mmap. However it only works when all processes are on the same node -  otherwise it produces rows of 0 for processors not on the rank 0 node, or other stray zeros in the output. Why is this? I feel I am missing something about how mmap works.

Edit: The same result occurs on both a NFS system, and on a parallel distributed system. A commenter below suggested it was to do with the page length of mmap. When the 'length' of my slice is exactly 4KiB the script still produces the  wrong output. The same also occurs when the slices are much longer than 4 KiB.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

length = int(1e6)      # Edited to make test case longer.
myfile = "/tmp/map"

if rank == 0:
    fp = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='w+', shape=(size,length))
    del fp

comm.Barrier()

fp = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='r+', shape=(1,length),
                offset=rank*length*4)
fp[:,:] = np.full(length,rank)

comm.Barrier()

if rank == 0:
    out = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='r', shape=(size,length))
    print(out[:,:])
```

Correct output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.]]
```

Incorrect output. Processors with rank 3 and 4 do not write.

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: I assume `/tmp/map` is a local file that only exists on the node where rank `0` is running.
I am surprised `memmap` did not fail on the other nodes (e.g. the file does not exist) though.

Comment: You are missing a network file system such as NFS (slow and general purpose, easy to deploy, hugely popular) or Lustre (fast and parallel, hard to deploy, used mostly in HPC).

Comment: I have tested this on both NFS and a parallel distributed filesystem, same problem in both cases.

Comment: That has to do with the fact that memory mapping works on page granularity. Pages are typically no smaller than 4 KiB. If you touch a single byte in a page, the whole page is marked dirty and then later flushed to the disk in its entirety. Whichever process comes last to flush its modified page over the network, will overwrite the changes made by the others. This is not a problem when all processes are on the same host since the same physical page from the FS cache is mapped in all of them. The solution is to not map such small areas but rather have at least 4 KiB per process.

Comment: Note that even though your arrays are `1 x 4 x 4 = 16` bytes, the size of the memory mapping is rounded up to a whole page and is also positioned to start on a page size boundary.

Comment: Have you considered using dask? https://dask.org/

Comment: @Tom I answered the question. Do you have any feedback on whether the solution works for you?

Comment: Sorry have been busy and still need to test and understand (I know very little about NFS/linux). Will do ASAP though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applies to NFS files. YMMV on other networked filesystems.

The problem is not related to MPI or `numpy.memmap` but to how the Linux kernel caches NFS file data. As far as I can tell from some experimentation, before requesting a read from the NFS server, the client requests the last-modified timestamp. If this timestamp is not more recent than the last write by the client, the data will be taken from the client's cache rather than be requested from the server again. If N1 and N2 are nodes, the following may happen:

1. N1 and N2 open the same zero-filled file; file content [00], last-modified: t=0.00.
2. The N1 and N2 kernels request more of the file content than needed and stores it in cache. N1 cache: [00] (t=0.00); N2 cache: [00] (t=0.00).
3. At time t=0.01, N2 writes to the second half of the file. Server state: [02] (t=0.01); N1 cache: [00] (0.00); N2 cache: [02] (0.01).
4. At time t=0.02, N1 writes to the first half. Server: [12] (0.02); N1 cache: [10] (0.02). N2 cache: [02] (0.01).
5. The process on N1 tries to read the second half.
6. The N1 kernel requests the last-modified time from the server; result: t=0.02.
7. The N1 kernel retrieves the stale cache content [0] for the first half.

Therefore, you need to ensure that other clients (nodes) update the timestamp.

```
if rank == 0:
    fp = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='w+', shape=(size,length))
    del fp

comm.Barrier() # B0
fp = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='r+', shape=(1,length),
                offset=rank*length*4)

comm.Barrier() # B1 (this one may be superfluous)
fp[:,:] = np.full(length, rank)
del fp # this will flush the changes to storage

comm.Barrier() # B2
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep
if rank == 1:
    # make sure that another node updates the timestamp
    # (assuming 1 s granularity on NFS timestamps)
    sleep(1.01)
    Path(myfile).touch()
    sleep(0.1) # not sure

comm.Barrier() # B3
if rank == 0:
    out = np.memmap(myfile, dtype=np.float32, mode='r', shape=(size,length))
    print(out[:,:])
```

About the barrier `B1`: I don't have MPI set up here; I simulated it with keypresses. I'm not sure that this barrier is really necessary. The `sleep(0.1)` may also not be necessary; it's just there in case of any latency between the `touch()` function returning and the NFS server receiving the update.

I have assumed that you arranged the data such that each node accesses parts of the memory-mapped file aligned to 4096-byte boundaries. I tested with `length=4096`.

This solution is a bit of a hack, relying on undocumented behavior of the NFS driver. This was on Linux kernel 3.10.0-957 with NFS mount options including `relatime,vers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192`. If you use this approach, I recommend that you include a self-test: basically, the above code with an `assert` statement to verify the output. That way, you will catch it if it stops working due to a different filesystem.